# Python: simple while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I need to genereate a random number between 1 and 9, both included and then ask the user to guess the number, and tell them whether they guessed too low, too high or right.

I checked many different answers and I just can't spot the error, but apparently, it gets stuck in the line of code just after the while statement and won't read the "if"s. I'm using Python 2.7.13. So here's the code:

```
import random

list1 = range(1, 10)
times =  0
numcpu = random.choice(list1)
running = True
while running:
    numhum = raw_input("Try to guess the random number between 1 and 9 the CPU generated: ")
    if numhum in list1:
        if numhum == numcpu:
            print ("You got it mate! It only took you " + times + " times")
            break
        else:
            print("Try again")
            continuar = str(input("Continue (y/n)?"))
            if continuar == "y":
                times = times + 1
            elif continuar == "n":
                print "Ciao"
            else:
                print "Don't mess around with me, human"
    elif numhum == "exit":
        print("Ciao")
        running = False
    else:
        "Don't mess around with me, human"
```

Comment: `if int(numhum) in list1` will work.

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input` instead of `input` in line

```
continuar = str(input("Continue (y/n)?"))
```